# Programmatically set the audio device being "listened" to in Windows

Tags: windows, audio

In Windows 7 you can go in to audio devices and check "Listen to this device", so the audio signal is played through speakers. Is there a way to set this, perhaps some variable in the Win32 API, so it can be changed without going in to the settings dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Not all audio devices on Windows support this option in the control panel.  But there's some docs on loopback recording on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316551%28VS.85%29.aspx